# Any historical references to links between JOSS and BASIC?

Tags: basic

I only recently learned of the JOSS language, and then only through a roundabout fashion from an [interview with David Ahl where he mentions FOCAL](https://computingpioneers.com/index.php/Dave_Ahl_and_Betsy_Ahl). This led me to read the available manuals for all versions of these languages. And that leads to a mystery...

[JOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOSS) is both a language and an operating system. It supports time-sharing and basic file management in addition to a user-facing editor and a program store. Users can enter commands/statements at the command line in "direct" mode where they run immediately, or they can prepend it with a line number, in which case it is entered into the store and can be performed by entering `Go` at the command prompt.

[Dartmouth BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_BASIC) is both a language and an operating system. It supports time-sharing and basic file management in addition to a user-facing editor and a program store. Users can enter commands/statements at the command line in "immediate" mode where they run immediately, or they can prepend it with a line number, in which case it is entered into the store and can be performed by entering `RUN` at the command prompt.

This may seem like a forced comparison. It is not. With one major exception, the two languages are almost identical and have 1:1 correspondence between instructions. JOSS has `Type`, BASIC has `PRINT`. JOSS has `Demand`, BASIC has `INPUT`. JOSS has `Set`, BASIC has `LET`. It's not just the instructions, the entire structure is similar.

The major difference is the structure of loops and conditionals. In BASIC, they precede the code they control, for instance, `IF X>5 THEN PRINT "YES!"`. In JOSS this order is reversed, `Type "YES!" if X>5`. I point this out because of one very interesting fact: BASIC-PLUS allowed either form, and I assume it took that note from JOSS. There are other differences, but overall they are minor.

And finally: JOSS began in 1961 and was running in 1963. It was *widely* shown to industry in 63 and 64. Dartmouth BASIC started in 1964 and was shipped that year.

Now my question. In spite of reading every history I can find for both languages, I cannot find any mention of JOSS as an inspiration for BASIC. Given the parallels between the two I find it difficult to believe JOSS was not known to the Dartmouth team.

So, does anyone know of an article on either that specifically links the two, or one of the many other offshoots of JOSS?

Comment: IF you look at an original tutorial like https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2006/RM5058.pdf, it seems more appropriate to say "except for the few simple examples you quoted, the entire structures of JOSS and BASIC are different." There is nothing in BASIC that corresponds to JOSS output formatting, "Type formula", "Do step" and "Do section", number dissection functions, iterators like "sum", "prod" and "first", etc, etc.

Comment: Note that in BASIC [as Dartmouth invented it](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dartmouth/BASIC_summary.pdf) and I learned it (I think some HP 2000 system), the only conditional was "IF relational-expression THEN line-number".

Comment: Overall, though, I think there's a certain inevitability to some constructs if you were inventing, in the 1960s/early 70s, what was essentially an interactive programmable calculator  BASIC mostly represents the table stakes.

Comment: Oh, and Dartmouth BASIC isn't an OS.  The OS is [DTSS](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dartmouth/DTSS_descr_Oct64.pdf).  Early versions may have had BASIC as the only compiler available, but that [changed](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dartmouth/The_Dartmouth_Time-Sharing_System_1980.pdf).

Comment: @another-dave - do you happen to have any materials relating to your dartmouth days? I'm desperately trying to get a user-submitted program listing but my emails to date have failed. Do you or anyone else you know might have one?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz  Alas, I think I was too terse above. As a schoolboy I had access to the Open University's (UK) online system, which I retroactively believe was running a Dartmouth-compatible version of BASIC. I have nothing remaining from way back then.  Sorry for any confusion/false hopes raised.

Comment: Oh darn. I would really like to credit the original author of Chase!

Answer (score 12):

I have a hard time to see any similarities beyond basic structures one will find in any language. And all of the ones cited are of such generic structure - heck, the very same list could be made for COBOL.

BASIC is clearly influenced by FORTRAN - up to the point of being a simplified FORTRAN. JOSS on the other hand focuses on a more natural language like structure with postfix modifiers/conditions. It is hard to find any influence from JOSS in BASIC. In fact, the Wiki article does JOSS a bad favour by referring to BASIC at all.

Of course, I wouldn't argue against being known to the designers of BASIC, but they clearly have decided to not go down the JOSS road.